# Change event description for organizer using VCalendar

Tags: outlook, imap, icalendar, vcalendar

currently we are using outlook to create a meeting and send it to email x . Whenever imap mailbox x gets an email it automatically parses and send updated iCal file (with new description) to all participants that was added and organizer. Everything is ok for all participants, except organizer, description in outlook calendar is not updating for organizer (old description is left). I am adding Sequence + 1 , changing timestamp, but still the same problem. Does that mean that for organizer there is no possible way to change description of already created event? Maybe there is any way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would say that this is the expected behavior. As the organizer, you are supposed to receive only REPLY, REFRESH, COUNTER, DECLINECOUNTER IMIP message. Anything else shall be ignored.

Comment: Yes I thought that, because of the security issues, so nobody else can't change the description and other info except the organizer. But is there any "hack" to overrride this?

Thank you