# How can I create and email an invite for two unrelated recipients to a meeting between them and allow them to control further scheduling

Tags: icalendar, ical4j

I have a system that matches two unrelated parties, after they engage through my system I want to enable them to schedule a meeting that will appear on their calendars.

It would be best that after the original scheduling they will be able to communicate over the event (accept, reject, reschedule etc. ) without me being the mediator (a bonus would be if I can be notified of any action they've taken).

I'm trying to achieve this creating the event using ical4j and sending it using Java Mail API 1.4.7. , but I don't mind other better options if available (even a 3rd party service).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the relationship between the two parties is somehow asymmetric, you can make one of them the ORGANIZER (and ATTENDEE with ROLE=CHAIR) and the other one an ATTENDEE (with ROLE=REQUIRED-PARTICIPANT). You can also add yourself as ATTENDEE (with ROLE=NON-PARTICIPANT).

If the relationship is strictly symmetric, then, unfortunately, iTIP/iMIP has no way to model that. So the best you can do is to put yourself as the ORGANIZER (but then you have to manage yourself the iMIP workflow, i.e. upon receiving a REPLY from one party, you will have to resend a REQUEST to the other party, etc...).

Comment: If i set one of them as the organizer as you suggested, will he still get the option to add the event to his calendar?

Comment: Is there a way to do accomplish this with Email Markup?

Comment: Should have thought about this, indeed, especially that I discussed this recently. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604423/when-creating-an-ical-event-on-behalf-of-an-organizer-and-email-it-to-him-no-a/35621380#35621380 . You are right. This may not work with all clients if everything is happening via iMIP.