# ics not updating organizer calendar

Tags: outlook, icalendar

I am writing an application that will send out .ics files to be interpreted mainly by outlook. When my applications sends an update, it will successfully update everyone's calendar except for the organizer's calendar. I'm using the same UID and I'm incrementing SEQUENCE each time. Is there anything else that I'm missing in my ICS file or does it not update my calendar because I am the organizer?

Below is an example of the ics code that we're using:

`BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 16.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Eastern Standard Time
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16011104T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:16010311T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0400
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;CN='test';RSVP=TRUE:mailto:test@testing.com
ATTENDEE;CN='attendee';RSVP=TRUE:mailto:attendee@attendees.com
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20180628T182531Z
DTSTART;TZID=Eastern Standard Time:20180630T141500
DTEND;TZID=Eastern Standard Time:20180630T160000
DTSTAMP:20180628T182531Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20180628T182531Z
LOCATION:some place
ORGANIZER;CN=Conference Room Board:mailto:test@testing.com
PRIORITY:5
SEQUENCE:1
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:test
TRANSP:OPAQUE
UID:SomeUniqueUID
CREATED:20180628T182531Z
DESCRIPTION:Test
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-AUTOFILLLOCATION:TRUE
X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR`

Thanks for any help!

Comment: A quick bit of googling indicates that this is quite probably a known Outlook bug.  Here's one such post withut resolution https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_windows8-mso_2010/outlook-calendar-not-updating-for-meeting/017dc719-9209-4394-9a6f-728353228a61    perhaps outlook assumes only the organiser would be doing updates?

Comment: After more research, I think that it is an outlook issue. When you normally try to send a meeting request in outlook, you can click and drag the meeting on your calendar and then send an update to all of the attendees. Sending the update appears to be working but it seems that the problem is trying to replicate that first action of "click and drag" through a third party program. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected. As the organiser, your client assumes that only itself is in control of invitation. As such it ignores invitations sent by other parties.
You may want to make the organiser also an ATTENDEE but there is no guarantee that this will work.

See [Change event description for organizer using VCalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35289089/change-event-description-for-organizer-using-vcalendar/35333570#35333570) and [When creating an iCal event on behalf of an organizer and email it to him, no "Add to calendar" or "RSVP" wrappers appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604423/when-creating-an-ical-event-on-behalf-of-an-organizer-and-email-it-to-him-no-a/35621380#35621380)

Answer (score 0):

So, you guys are correct and this is expected behavior. I tried adding the organiser as an attendee and ended up running into problems when I tried to create an event cancellation. The organiser would receive the email but be unable to remove from calendar because they were recognized as the organizer.

I ended up abandoning using ICS files and instead started using a library that communicates through Exchange Web Services. EWS allowed me to simulate creating a meeting on someone's calendar through an API and then adding attendees just like I created the meeting in Outlook. Specifically, I was using python so I started using [Exchangelib](https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib).

I wanted to put an answer to this question for anyone else that may stumble upon this.