# Meeting Invite doesn't show up in my Calendar

Tags: php, office365, meeting-request

I have working Code for sending meetings invites using php, every thing working  fine for me, email invite send to all selected email addresses. But i face one issue, meeting invite generated by this code, doesn't show up in my calendar, although it show up to all attendees.

Here is my Function for meeting Invite.

```
function send_calendar_invite ($to,$str_cc,$str_bcc,$subject,$body,$from_addr,$from_name,$from_password,$meeting_date,$meeting_duration,$meeting_location)
{

  if($str_cc!='')
  {
    $cc_addr=explode(",",$str_cc);
    $cc_cnt=count($cc_addr);
  }

  if($str_bcc!='')
  {
    $bcc_addr=explode(",",$str_bcc);
    $bcc_cnt=count($bcc_addr);
  }

  $to_addr = explode(",",$to);
  $to_cnt=count($to_addr);


  //Convert MYSQL datetime and construct iCal start, end and issue dates
  $meetingstamp = strtotime($meeting_date. " UTC");    
  $dtstart= gmdate("Ymd\THis",$meetingstamp);
  $dtend= gmdate("Ymd\THis",$meetingstamp+$meeting_duration);
  $todaystamp = gmdate("Ymd\THis");
  
  //Create unique identifier
  $cal_uid = date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."-".rand()."@outlook.com";

  //Create Email Headers
  $headers = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_addr.">\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$from_name." <".$from_addr.">\n";


  //Create Email Body (HTML)
  $message = '';
  $message .= "<html>\n";
  $message .= "<body>\n";
  $message .= '<p>Hi All,</p>';
  $message .= $body;    
  $message .= "</body>\n";
  $message .= "</html>\n";
  
  
  //Create ICAL Content (Google rfc 2445 for details and examples of usage) 
  $ical = 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR' . "\r\n" .
  'PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 10.0 MIMEDIR//EN' . "\r\n" .
  'VERSION:2.0' . "\r\n" .
  'METHOD:REQUEST' . "\r\n" .
  'BEGIN:VTIMEZONE' . "\r\n" .
  'TZID:Eastern Standard Time' . "\r\n" .
  'BEGIN:STANDARD' . "\r\n" .
  'DTSTART:16011104T020000' . "\r\n" .
  'RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11' . "\r\n" .
  'TZOFFSETFROM:-0400' . "\r\n" .
  'TZOFFSETTO:-0500' . "\r\n" .
  'TZNAME:Eastern Standard Time' . "\r\n" .
  'END:STANDARD' . "\r\n" .
  'BEGIN:DAYLIGHT' . "\r\n" .
  'DTSTART:16010311T020000' . "\r\n" .
  'RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3' . "\r\n" .
  'TZOFFSETFROM:-0500' . "\r\n" .
  'TZOFFSETTO:-0400' . "\r\n" .
  'TZNAME:Eastern Standard Time' . "\r\n" .
  'END:DAYLIGHT' . "\r\n" .
  'END:VTIMEZONE' . "\r\n" .  
  'BEGIN:VEVENT' . "\r\n" .
  'ORGANIZER;CN="'.$from_name.'":MAILTO:'.$from_addr. "\r\n";
  for($i=0;$i<$to_cnt;$i++)
  {
      $ical .='ATTENDEE;CN="'.$to_addr[$i].'";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:'.$to_addr[$i]. "\r\n";
  }
  $ical .='LAST-MODIFIED:' . date("Ymd\TGis") . "\r\n" .
  'UID:'.date("Ymd\TGis", strtotime($startTime)).rand()."@outlook.com \r\n" .
  'DTSTAMP:'.date("Ymd\TGis"). "\r\n" .
  'DTSTART;TZID="Eastern Standard Time":'.$dtstart. "\r\n" .
  'DTEND;TZID="Eastern Standard Time":'.$dtend. "\r\n" .
  'TRANSP:OPAQUE'. "\r\n" .
  'SEQUENCE:1'. "\r\n" .
  'SUMMARY:' . $subject . "\r\n" .
  'LOCATION:' . $meeting_location . "\r\n" .
  'CLASS:PUBLIC'. "\r\n" .
  'PRIORITY:5'. "\r\n" .
  'BEGIN:VALARM' . "\r\n" .
  'TRIGGER:-PT15M' . "\r\n" .
  'ACTION:DISPLAY' . "\r\n" .
  'DESCRIPTION:Reminder' . "\r\n" .
  'END:VALARM' . "\r\n" .
  'END:VEVENT'. "\r\n" .
  'END:VCALENDAR'. "\r\n";



  $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
  try {
      //Server settings
     //$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
      $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
      $mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
      $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
      $mail->Username = $from_addr;                 // SMTP username
      $mail->Password = $from_password;                           // SMTP password
      $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
      $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
      //Recipients
      $mail->setFrom($from_addr, $from_name);
      for($i=0;$i<$to_cnt;$i++)
      {
        $mail->addAddress(trim($to_addr[$i]));
      }
      
    
    $mail->addReplyTo($from_addr, $from_name);

    if($cc_cnt>=0)
    {
      for($i=0;$i<$cc_cnt;$i++)
      {
        //echo $cc_addr[$i] . "test";
        $mail->addCC(trim($cc_addr[$i]));
      }
    }

    if($bcc_cnt>=0)
    {
      for($i=0;$i<$bcc_cnt;$i++)
      {
        $mail->addBCC(trim($bcc_addr[$i]));
      }
    }
  

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = $message;
    $mail->AltBody = $message;
    $mail->AddStringAttachment("$ical", "meeting.ics", "base64", "text/calendar; charset=utf-8; method=REQUEST");

    $mail->send();
    //echo 'Message has been sent';
    return "sent";
  } catch (Exception $e) {
      //echo 'Message could not be sent.';
      //echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    return "failed";
  }

}
```

Please help me what is the the error why meeting invite isn't showing up in my calendar.

Comment: Quick fix maybe add yourself as an attendee also? That is, should the organizer also be an attendee.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iCal not showing meeting time slot for organizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52364578/ical-not-showing-meeting-time-slot-for-organizer) Think I guessed it. Recall the specs on vcal stuff was always spotty to non existent.

Comment: I have also added my-self as attendee, but it still didn't show time slot in my calendar.

Comment: Voted to reopen. Is it just something with your calendar? Test on other machine or something?

Comment: I think something i am missing in my code, i don't know what is it. i have tried with 3 different outlook accounts. but i cant get the time slot in my calendar.

Comment: Does you being an attendee but not an organizer let you add it to your calendar? Trying to verify the same thing still.

Comment: Sorry i can't get, what you are saying

Comment: So, you say it works for the attendees. If you create an invite, where you are *not* an organizer but just an attendee, can *you* then get it to add to your calendar?

Comment: Seen this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61618410/ical-event-not-added-into-organizer-calendar

Comment: Yes, if i use my web@xyz.com account and insert myname@xyz.com as attendee. myname@xyz.com will get invite and also showed up in calendar. but web@xyz.com calendar will be empty no timeslot for organizer and also organizer cant edit or reschedule meeting

Comment: **Seen this one? stackoverflow.com/questions/61618410/… – ficuscr 1 hour ago**
this isnt the working for me